# How to create Java VM in C?

Tags: java, c

I have written code to create Java VM:

```
JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **) &env, (void *)&args);
```

And when I run my program this text shows:

> jvm.dll not found

and I copied "jvm.dll" to the main directory of program. Now I have this message in console:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Unable to load native library: Can't find dependent libraries

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the library path as a VM argument and make sure that all required `.dll` files are present in `/path/to/dir` :

```
-Djava.library.path=/path/to/dir
```